# How to write Dynamic Transaction names with loop count in truclient

Tags: dynamic, transactions, truclient

I want to define dynamic transaction name with a variable in it
like
for(var i=0;i<=5;i++)

LR.startTransaction("Application_TransactionLoopcount_"+myloopcount);
Truclient step1
Truclient step2

LR.endTransaction("Application_TransactionLoopcount_"+myloopcount, "Auto");

Expecting transaction like: Application_TransactionLoopcount_1

But always throwing an syntax expection
Pls advice

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do so using TC.startTransaction and TC.endTransaction.

Make sure the steps are wrapped in TC ForLoop step and you use the index variable name in your JavaScript steps.

`TC.startTransaction("Transaction_LoopCount" + i);`

`TC.endTransaction("Transaction_LoopCount" + i, "Auto");`

In case you still have an exception, it would be worth to paste the exception here as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work but it's going to be hard give an exact answer without the exception you see.

For example: [Dynamic Transaction Names in TruClient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydO2I.png)

These are the results: [Vugen Output log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlKoa.png)

Your code does not have "myloopcount" defined.  I get an error if the variable in the transaction statement is undefined:

[Exception Reference is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG2C8.png)